# error MSB3073: Visual studio 2010, windows7

Tags: msbuild, batch-file

```
error MSB3073: The command "

if "%OS%"=="" goto NOTNT
if not "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" goto NOTNT
"EventController.exe" /RegServer
echo regsvr32 exec. time > "UnicodeDebug\regsvr32.trg"
echo Server registration done!
goto end
:NOTNT
echo Warning : Cannot register Unicode EXE on Windows 95
:end
:VCEnd"
exited with code 9009.
```

How to handle this error. Help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: doesn't look like a c++ program

Comment: it is not a c++ program, it is error: actually i was unable to post it as plain text. I need to know how to fix this error ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is mostly guesswork, but I'm feeling adventurous today :-)

Based on the bad formatting of your code fragement (which I liberally adjusted) it is a bit hard to tell, but the most likely cause is that a command was not found.

Background:

What you have here is not c++ code and has as such nothing to do with compilation. Again I took the liberty to change the tags accordingly. It is a batch (fragment), which from the error code `MSB....` seems to be executed by MSBuild during your build process, which might be the reason why you "assumed" it has something to do with C++ or the compiler.

Now, the actual clue lies in the exit code "9009" which is the same error code that you get when you try to invoke a command / executable, that does not exist or cannot be found, from the command prompt.

So, most likely one of the commands in the fragment you show does not exist or cannot be found. I would assume it is the "EventController.exe" executable.